# Theoretical - JavaScript link redirection security issue

Tags: javascript, security, xss

The following is a theoretical question, that I hope someone will be able to provide with an answer.

I've explored a bit and found that the following is very (dangerously) possible:

```
$('#link').click(function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.malicious-example.com';
    return false;
});
```

**[As seen in this live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2JSCM/)**

---

Now I may not be very sharp at JavaScript, but this seems like a gigantic security hole, I mean, the browser thinks and shows (in the bottom) that the link is indeed going to http://google.com, when it will eventually lead to http://www.malicious-example.com.

Does anyone have any information of this issue? Are there measures taken to take care of it?

Comment: I think a broad term called 'Phishing' is what you are trying to address.

Comment: if you fell this is a issue dont use javascript

Comment: That's poor usability design, not a security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much that can be done about it and to be honest I hardly see the concern. Barely visiting a webpage can rarely be harmful and if a site was to do that, why not simply redirect the user as soon as the page loads?

There used to be some issues with JavaScript, mainly related to alerts and the ability to cancel a page change, but most proper browsers have dealth with them in various ways. For example, if two alerts are made very quickly you will have the option of turning off all further alerts, and browsers now detect if the page is attempting to stop the user from leaving and will output their own message.

Comment: "barely visiting a webpage can rarely be harmful" - not true. Suppose I get you to visit a webpage, and I put JS on the page to initiate a request to your bank. If the request is `POST /transfer?to=attacker&amount=99999` - unless your bank has taken specific steps to address this problem, the attacker may well be able to initiate a transfer. This is called Cross Site Request Forgery, and is just one way 'just visiting' a webpage can be very harmful

Comment: I'd argue my "rarely" makes my statement true. CORS would prevent that from happening with a POST request. You could use an image if your bank did transfers in a single step using GET requests, but I'd be willing to go as far as to say that such a bank website is going to be, more than rare, impossible to find.

Answer (score 0):

This illustrates very well the difference between a pure html web page and a javascripted page. A web page with javascript is actually a tiny program. When you run this program, you have to trust the programmer to some degree. The programmer may "re-program" the link as you demonstrates, but he can do more than that. He don't have to wait for you to click a link. He can tie that action to i.e. hovering the mouse over an image or another totally innocent action.

Javascript is a powerful language. That makes it useful, but it also makes it potentially dangerous in much the same way as programs written in other programming languages.